# Can I send a function as a parameter to all processes with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I've got a use case for multiprocessing where I want to write a dispatch function that receives as input a python function and an input queue, and then dispatches that function over that input through multiprocessing?

I'm not sure if `args` is the appropriate thing to pass in, since the function isn't strictly going to be shared.

```
import multiprocessing

def dispatch(queue, function):
    while True:
        if queue.empty():
            return
        current_project = queue.get()
        function(current_project)

def letter_rip(projects_filename, function):
    project_file = open(projects_filename, 'r')
    projects = project_file.readlines()
    project_file.close()

    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for project in projects:
        q.put(project)

    for i in xrange(0, 128):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=dispatch, args=(q, ???function??? ))
        p.start()
```

Comment: Do you want to share a source code of function or function entity itself? In first case the plain .py file is a good option from my point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are (when used as functions and not as objects) immutable objects so no problems should araise from their plain usage:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

def callback(x):
    return x * 2

def handler(x, fn, a):
    a.value = fn(x.value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Value('d', 2)
    a = Value('d', 0)
    p1 = Process(target=handler, args=(x, callback, a))
    p2 = Process(target=handler, args=(x, callback, a))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    print a.value
```